# Broadcast receiver doesnt broadcast in given time

Tags: android

This is my SetAlarm.class. here i set time and date according to calendar.

```
             Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
             date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
            date.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
            date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            date.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(SetAlarm.this,       MyReceiver.class);
           pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetAlarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And this is my receiver class where toast is to be shown.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Birthday Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Calendar` months are zero-based: January=0, February=1.  The date you show in your code is for February 29th.  Also, [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) is used for the 24 hour clock.  For example, to specify 10PM `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22)`.  You should not use `HOUR_OF_DAY` and `AM_PM` together.  When using [AM_PM](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM), set the hour with `HOUR`, not `HOUR_OF_DAY`.